# Finding items inside a vector of map given a key (C++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, pointers, vector, quantlib

I was trying to debug a coding (C++ / Quantlib) using vector of maps. Basically I would like to find an item inside a map which is in turn inside a vector. But caught error.

input:

```
vector<map <Date, Real> > simulatedPrices_;    // a vector containing 1000 maps
vector<Date> cds_maturities_;
```

private variable:

```
map <Date, Real> pricePathJ;    // for reading each map in the vector
Real w_t_;    //
```

coding:

```
for (int j = 0; j < no_of_paths; j++) {
    pricePathJ = simulatedPrices_[j];
    for (int i = 0; i <= iTenor_; i++) {    //iTenor is the number of element inside vector cds_maturities_
        startDate = ......;
        endDate = ......;
        w_t_ = pricePathJ.find(cds_maturities_[i]);    // error in pricePathJ saying there is no conversion function from iterator ... the pair<Date, Real> to Real. 
        ......
```

Did I commit any mistakes or if there's any pointer type that I overlooked in the above coding? Thanks.

Remarks: variable type Real is simular to type Double

Comment: What is the type of `w_t_`? if its not a iterator well that explains your error because that is what `find()` returns.

Comment: What do you want to do when you find it?

Comment: The code doesn't make sense. Why do you loop if you only act when `i == iTenor_`? What type is `cds_maturities_`?

Comment: Sorry I missed details of this coding. w_t_ was actually of type "Real" (simular to type "Double"). I want to find the key (Date) and the map return me the item (Real) (so that I can use the value to do some other calculation). So I must change w_t_ to type vector<map<Date,Real>>::iterator? Can't I read the value directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a simple for loop and use map's `find()` function to do this.  It will return the first `Real` that matches

```
Real FindReal(const std::vector<std::map<Date, Real>> & data, const Date & findDate)
{
    for (auto&& e : data)
    {
        auto it = e.find(findDate);
        if (it != e.end())
            return it->second;
    }
    return some_value_if_not_found;
}
```

Comment: That's going to do a whole lot of copying

Comment: @zmb It should be better now.  I added a universal reference to the loop and get the variables by `const&`